# Combinatorics of Abelian group subsets

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, abelian-groups

Consider a finite group $G$, in which every element is its own inverse (the group is Abelian), and a subset $S$ of elements from $G$, that does not include the identity.

I am interested in answering: how many ordered products of $L$ elements from $S$ evaluate to the identity? For example, for $L=2$ the answer is trivially $|S|$.

Is there an efficient way to solve this problem analytically or numerically for an arbitrary $L$ given $S$? Does this problem resemble a known problem in group theory or combinatorics?

Comment: Insufficient information.  For example, suppose that $G$ is the set $$\{e, x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_9\}.$$  Further suppose that $S$ is the set $$\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\}$$ and $L = 3.$  In order to determine whether for example $x_1 \times x_2 \times x_3 = e$, you have to determine whether $x_1 \times x_2 = x_3$.  So, in the case of $L = 3$, you need to know how many of the $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} = 6~$ products $x_a \times x_b$ will be such that $(x_a \times x_b) \in S.$

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the optimal strategy for solving such problems, not an explicit solution, which one can indeed find only once one is given $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for a moment each element of $S$ could be used only once in each product.

Any such group $G$ can be thought of as a finite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb F_2$, the field with two elements. Once a basis is chosen for that vector space and each element of $S$ written in that basis, the problem becomes determining the null space of the matrix whose columns are the elements of $S$: that null space can be enumerated, and its elements partitioned according to Hamming weight, which corresponds to the length $L$ of an unordered product of distinct elements of $S$. From here, one can multiply by $L!$ to find the number of ordered products.

If we go back to allowing elements with multiplicity, then one can pre-sort by the pairs of elements of the ordered product that have equal entries, and count the remaining elements using the above method.

(One could alternatively write the number of ordered products directly using exponential sums over $G$ and try to evaluate or estimate the resulting exponential sum.)

Answer (score 0):

With this setting, $G$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^d$ for some $d\in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore the question you are asking can be rephrased in terms of linear algebra. Once you have a basis for your $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-vector space, you can easily solve the question 'coordinates by coordinates'.

Comment: This doesn't take into account possible repetition of elements.